# How to get DiffMerge configured to work with Git on Windows 7 or Windows 2012?

Tags: git, diffmerge

So I've seen a few questions about getting DiffMerge to be the `mergetool` and `difftool` for git.  Essentially it comes down to having DiffMerge (sgdm.exe) in your `PATH` and a `.gitconfig` that looks like:

```
[diff]
    tool = DiffMerge
[difftool "DiffMerge"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe' "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
[merge]
    tool = DiffMerge
[mergetool "DiffMerge"]
    cmd = 'C:/Program Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe' -merge -result="$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"
    trustExitCode = true
    keepBackup = false
```

When I run `git difftool file1 file2`, nothing happens.  No error code, no launching of DiffMerge.  From Git Bash and a Windows Command Line, I can run `sgdm file1 file2` and DiffMerge comes up.

I've modified the `cmd` in the `.gitconfig` to not have a path or extensions (e.g. `sgdm` only), but still to no avail.

Has anyone encountered this?  Are there some obvious things I'm missing?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 14):

My `.gitconfig` for using SourceGear DiffMerge is:

```
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
cmd = \"C:\\program files\\sourcegear\\common\\diffmerge\\sgdm.exe\" --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
```

(Obviously, flip `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` if you prefer them on the other side.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, I'm still getting the same behavior -- nothing launches, no error, nothing.  I'm using msysgit 1.8 if that matters.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm using 1.7.10.msysgit.1.  I'll try to upgrade later to see if that's the difference.

Answer (score 8):

following worked for me-

```
git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd 'C:/Program\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode true
git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd 'C:/Program\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe -merge -result="$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"'
```

Answer (score 5):

This has worked well for me for quite a while.  (Windows 7, latest version of Git.)

Make sure sgdm.exe is in the environment path.

```
[diff]
    tool = sgdm
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = sgdm $LOCAL $REMOTE
[merge]
    tool = sgdm
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = sgdm --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
    trustexitcode = false
[difftool "sgdm"]
    cmd = sgdm $LOCAL $REMOTE
[mergetool "sgdm"]
    trustexitcode = false
    cmd = sgdm --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $MERGED $REMOTE --title1=Mine --title2='Merged: $MERGED' --title3=Theirs
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__git__windows__msysgit.html) worked for me:

```
C:\> git config --global diff.tool diffmerge
C:\> git config --global difftool.diffmerge.cmd
    "C:/Program\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe
        \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""

C:\> git config --global merge.tool diffmerge
C:\> git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.trustExitCode true
C:\> git config --global mergetool.diffmerge.cmd 
    "C:/Program\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe
        /merge /result=\"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\""
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me with Git 1.7.9 and Windows 7 64 bit. My starting point is the Pro Git book http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration. The changes for Windows vs Mac were a) for diff, just replacing / with \\ and putting quotes round the path containing a space b) for merge the parameters are the same as yours but with quotes. Thus:

**.gitconfig**

```
[merge]
     tool = extMerge
[mergetool "extMerge"]
    cmd = extMerge "$BASE" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE" "$MERGED"
    trustExitCode = false
[diff]
    external = extDiff
```

Two script files that are on your PATH

**extMerge**

```
#!/bin/sh
"C:\\Program Files\\SourceGear\\Common\\DiffMerge\\sgdm.exe" "-merge" "-result=$4" "$2" "$1" "$3"
```

**extDiff**

```
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -eq 7 ] && "C:\\Program Files\\SourceGear\\Common\\DiffMerge\\sgdm.exe" "$2" "$5"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one did it for me when none of the other's did:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
[user]
    email = XYZ
    name = ABC
[merge]
    tool = diffmerge
[mergetool "diffmerge"]
    trustExitCode = true
    cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe --merge --result=$MERGED $LOCAL $BASE $REMOTE
[mergetool]
    keepBackup = false
[difftool "diffmerge"]
    cmd = C:/Program\\ Files/SourceGear/Common/DiffMerge/sgdm.exe \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[diff]
    tool = diffmerge
[push]
    default = matching
```